# How do I map JSON data that is passed into a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, charts

Im trying to take JSON data and pass it into my 'HistoryChart' Component to try and map the dates and prices into two arrays so that I can present them on my chart. However, I keep getting undefined errors.

Here is the JSON Data:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "",
    "brand": "",
    "image": "",
    "sources": [],
    "history": [
        {
            "_id": 3,
            "price": "299.99",
            "product": 1,
            "date": "2021-07-01"
        },
        {
            "_id": 4,
            "price": "399.99",
            "product": 1,
            "date": "2021-07-08"
        },
        {
            "_id": 5,
            "price": "499.99",
            "product": 1,
            "date": "2021-07-15"
        },
        {
            "_id": 6,
            "price": "599.99",
            "product": 1,
            "date": "2021-07-22"
        },
        {
            "_id": 7,
            "price": "699.99",
            "product": 1,
            "date": "2021-07-29"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my HistoryChart Component:

```
function HistoryChart({product}) {
 
    var dates = product.history.map(function(e){ //<-- The Problem lies here where it says cannot map undefined.
        return e.date;
    });

    var prices = product.history.map(function(e){
        return e.price;
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <Line
                data={{
                    labels: dates,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: `Average Price History (ID: ${product._id})`, //<-- This part works
                        backgroundColor:/* 'transparent' */ '#00ad0e',
                        borderColor: '#00ad0e',
                        data: prices,
                    }]
                }}
                width={100}
                height={50}
                options={{ maintainAspectRatio: true }}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

I am also using redux to get the Data:

```
const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.productDetails)
const {error, loading, product} = productDetails
```

And the data is passed into the HistoryChart Component like this:

```
 <HistoryChart product={product}/>
```

Any Help would be Much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your'e passing the correct object? maybe you're wrapping it in another one. Can you `console.log(product)` in `HistoryChart()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if this is not your principal problem, but same time when .map resulting in undefined the most simple adjust is verify if your array is undefined.

So in my projects i always check first if array is undefined, i will use your code to do a example

```
  function HistoryChart({product}) {
     
if (product !== undefined){
        var dates = product.history.map(function(e){ 
            return e.date;
        });

    
        var prices = product.history.map(function(e){
            return e.price;
        });
}
```

Try this aproach and let me know if this work.

Comment: I tried your approach, but it still says 'cannot map undefined', however when used 'if (product.history !== undefined)' it worked, but I'm not really sure why.

Comment: Ow, now checking again, i forgot to specify .history, you need to do that because you have a array in this node of your Json, so you can get a Json and  have a history array undefined inside the Json, that why you need to check!

Comment: I understand now, Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Cause of Error**

As the data come from server, it take some time to load. and you get the undefine error because 1st time you want to access `history` of object `product` which is not yet loaded successfully.

**Solution**

```
const price = product && product.history.map(//do what you want)
```

use key values of object this way not cause any error because if product is not loaded it does'nt call map function and when product object loaded successfully it will call map function